# AWS Lambda + API integration returning as plain text instead of a downloadable .csv

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Im working on a basic API lambda function written in Node.js with Api gateway integration where my goal is to get a file from S3 as a downloadable object (in this case its a .csv file). The API works but it returns as a plain text inside the browser and the data does not look like the data inside the csv.

I don't get any errors so I don't understand where my problem lies. Any thoughts? Thanks!

This is the node.js code:

```
console.log('Loading function');
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new aws.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
const params = {
    Bucket: 'testing-api-lambda-s3-jfr',
    Key: 'sample-file-testing.csv',
};

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  s3.getObject(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      reject({
        statusCode: 500,
        error: JSON.stringify(err)
      });
    }
  resolve({
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Content-Type": "text/csv"
    },
    body: data
  });

  });
});
 };
```

Api gatewayflow:
[image]

API call returns like this instead of a downloadable .csv file:
[image]

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/lambda-proxy-binary-media.html Note section

Answer (score 0):

Convert the S3 `Buffer` data to a `string`, which the [API Gateway proxy response expects](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/7467038c60726c43ccfc0f084cd8d5d8f062d234/types/aws-lambda/trigger/api-gateway-proxy.d.ts#L128).  Return `body: dataString` in the response.

```js
const dataString = data.Body.toString('utf-8'); // set encoding as necessary
```

Add a [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header to your response to get the desired file download behaviour:

```js
'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=download.csv'
```

Comment: That didn't work

Comment: What are the response headers?  Check in dev tools or make the request in cURL or Postman.

Comment: Returns OK with headers "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
Content-Disposition: "attachment; filename=\"sample-file-testing.csv\""
Content-Type: "text/csv"" but still seeing the same behavior instead of a downloadble file

Comment: Can you try it with `inline` in the Content-Disposition instead of `attachment`?

Comment: @fedonev I open the URL on new private window, same thing. I make sure my changes are deployed. Not working unfortunately

Comment: @stdunbar i tried this as well, its the same behavior.

Comment: @jfr01 The new header was necessary but not sufficient.  You need to fix an unrelated problem. The response `body` needs to be a `string`.  See the edited answer.  I finally decided to read the tiny print on the output screenshot. Your browser is getting back the JSON response object including `headers` and `statusCode`.  That's not right.  Fingers crossed the string body type will fix that.  When I asked you about the header values, Are you 100% sure you checked the response headers \*\*in the network tab of dev tools\*\*?  Or did you give me the header values you see in the browser window?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem after I enable the "Use Lambda Proxy integration" checkbox in this GET method setting of API gateway.

Lambda function code:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    
    
    // TODO implement
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
                'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="text.txt"'
        },
        body: 'Hello from Lambda!',
        isBase64Encoded: false
    };
    return response;
};
```

After deploy the API gateway setting, click the url link, I can download a text.txt file from Chrome browser.
The text.txt just shows Hello from Lambda!